# json object returned by http response

Tags: python, json, django, unicode, python-requests

I am using python and django to develop some REST APIs. I have a question about the JSON unicode string returned by the requests call. So, I am doing something like:

```
resp = requests.get(self.url)
if resp.status_code is status.HTTP_200_OK:
    obj = json.loads(resp.json())
```

With this I can iterate over the entries as:

```
for o in obj:
    print o
```

This prints something like:

```
{u'pk': 1, u'model': u'aslapp.imagetypemodel', u'fields': {u'type': u'PNG'}}
{u'pk': 2, u'model': u'aslapp.imagetypemodel', u'fields': {u'type': u'JPG'}}
```

However, I read that the `resp.json()` call should call this `json.loads()` method internally and will take care of the encoding stuff. However, just doing:

```
obj = resp.json()
for o in obj:
    print o
```

Just iterates over each character in the unicode string. So am I supposed to run it through the `loads` method again if I want to iterate through the JSON entries? What would be the correct way to iterate through all the JSON records returned returned by `resp.json()`.

Comment: I'm a little confused - `requests.get` is related to django or [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, `resp.json()` does call `json.loads()` for you.

Therefore, if `resp.json()` returns a string, then that suggests that the API has json encoded the data twice. For example, it is returning `"{\"pk\": 1}"` instead of `{"pk": 1}`.

If you don't have any control over the API, then you'll have to decode it twice to get the Python object.

Comment: Right. So on the django side, the returned data is `data = serializers.serialize("json", types) return Response(data)`

Comment: @Luca Django also has a `JsonResponse` which you can pass objects like dicts or lists directly.

Comment: If Response is from DRF, then it will serialize things for you; as the DRF docs note, you should pass in Python primitives (eg dicts and lists) rather than already-rendered JSON. Use the standard HttpResponse, or use DRF's serializers rather than the Django ones.

Comment: @Luca Sound advice by Daniel Roseman. (DRF = django-rest-framework) You should definitely consider it if you are building an API.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestions!

Comment: Thanks again to all. I was able to use the `Serializer` classes from DRF and learn something new in the process!